# Create foreign key constraint on JSON column

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

JSON support in SQL Server is pretty new. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/store-json-documents-in-sql-tables?view=sql-server-2017) for more information.

We would like to use this to store our translatable fields. This means in the database we would no longer have a separate table with translations but instead store them in the column itself.

Our column value would look like this:

```
"Name" : {
    "en-US" : "Conditioning",
    "nl-NL" : "Behandeling",
    "fr-FR" : "Traitement",
    "de-DE" : "Konditionierung"
}
```

Since we still have a table with all the different cultures I would still like to apply a foreign key relation between Name.Key and the Culture table.

I couldn't find any information on how to apply foreign key constraints to the data in the JSON. Does anyone have a clue how to?

I've tried the constraint below for testing but this does not work. The `JSON_VALUE` does not seem to work on JSON keys. Whereas `JSON_QUERY` returns more than just the key.

```
ADD CONSTRAINT
    [FK_ItemCulture]
CHECK (JSON_VALUE([Name], '$.Name') IN ('en-US', 'nl-NL', 'fr-FR', 'de-DE'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a scalar function that will check a single json:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[svf_CheckJsonNames](@json nvarchar(max))
RETURNS bit AS
BEGIN
    declare @ok bit
    declare @validNames table([name] nvarchar(50))

    insert into @validNames values ('en-US'),('nl-NL'),('fr-FR'),('de-DE')

    if exists (
            select x.[key] , vn.name  from OPENJSON (@json)  
            with (
                [Name] nvarchar(max) as json
            ) t
            cross apply 
            (
            select [key] from openjson(t.[Name])
            ) x
            left join  @validNames vn
            on x.[key] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = vn.[name] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
            where vn.[name] is null
        )
        set @ok = 0
    else set @ok = 1

    RETURN @ok
END
```

The functions returns 1 if all names are valid, 0 if one or more names are invalid.

Now you can use this function in your constraint:

```
create table tmp(myId int, [Name] nvarchar(max))

alter table tmp ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ItemCulture]
    CHECK ([dbo].[svf_CheckJsonNames]([Name]) = 1)
```

if you run the following insert statements:

```
insert into tmp values(1, '{"Name" : { "en-US" : "Conditioning", "nl-NL" : "Behandeling", "fr-FR" : "Traitement", "de-DE" : "Konditionierung" }}')
insert into tmp values(2, '{"Name" : { "en-EN" : "Conditioning", "nl-NL" : "Behandeling", "fr-FR" : "Traitement", "de-DE" : "Konditionierung" }}')
```

the first will succed because all names are correct:

[image]

but the second will fail since the first name ("en-EN") is invalid. Here is the error:

[image]

Comment: So, the strict answer to the original question is NO.  In fact, lack of support for this feature across the SQL vendors is both consistent and understandable. As a workaround you can, as proposed by Andrea, have a check constraint, but it is NOT a FK constraint, because, in part, it does not help on the parent side of the relationship: I can't have a delete of a parent key failed if a reference exists, unless I hack up a similar check constraint on the referenced side, and even then I surely won't be able to delete with the cascade option.